# iOS — Is it Acceptable to Set Initial View as Advertisements for x Number of Seconds Right After Launch Image?

Tags: ios, view, ads

I'm asking if such activity would be acceptable when submitting the app.

As soon as my app starts, the launch image containing the company logo then redirects to a screen containing ads, then after a couple of seconds the app starts.

Does this violate any human interface guidelines?

Comment: Depends, do you like one-star reviews and annoying your users?

Comment: It's a client request. I understand what you are saying, which is why I need an excuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html), emphasis mine:

> Brand Appropriately
>
> Incorporate a brand’s colors or images in a refined, unobtrusive way. Branding is most effective when it is subtle and understated. **People use your application to get things done or to be entertained; they don’t want to feel as if they’re being forced to watch an advertisement.** For the best user experience, you want to quietly remind users of your identity.

And:

> Start Instantly
>
> It’s often said that people spend no more than a minute or two evaluating a new app. When you make the most of this brief period by presenting useful content immediately, you pique the interest of new users and give all users a superior experience.
>
> Display a launch image that closely resembles the first screen of the application. This practice decreases the perceived launch time of your application.
>
> **Avoid displaying an About window or a splash screen. In general, try to avoid providing any type of startup experience that prevents people from using your application immediately.**

Your client's requests directly contradict these guidelines. It is part of your job as a developer to refuse idiotic or incorrect requests from your clients, for the good of both of you! I hope these exerpts help you with that.